# множественный запуск ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть страница данные для которой берутся посредством вызова ajax при при ее загрузке

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

      getItems(adminPageSize, null, false, false);
   });

  function getItems(pageSize, firstKey, isReverse, includePreviousKey) {

            var userName = getSessionEmail();
            var sessionID = getSessionID();

            var requestData = createRequest(userName, sessionID, adminPageSize, firstKey, isReverse, includePreviousKey);

            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + '/admins/list',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                contentType: "application/json",
                asynk: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    var status = data.status;
                    var message = data.errorMessage;

                    if (status == "SUCCESS") {
                        if (isReverse)
                            data.data.reverse();
                        writeBody(data);
                    }
                    else if (status == "ERROR") {
                        if (validateAuthError(message))
                            return;

                        showInfo(message, "Error");
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    ajaxErrorProcessing(xhr.status);

                    showInfo("unexpected error occurred by accessing to " + hostUrl);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

переход на страницу осуществляется по ссылке :

```
<a id="btnAdministra" href="Administrators.html">Administrators</a>
```

При множественном нажатии на выше указанную ссылку происходит несколько одновременных запросов и страница падает. Как можно сделать чтобы чтобы страница загружалась только один раз независимо от того сколько раз на нее кликнули ?

Comment: уточню: у вас происходит несколько ajax запросов при судорожном нажатии на ссылку, вам надо сделать только один?

Comment: введите доп. переменную флаг, о нажатии, нажал, изменил в фальш, и больше не посылать аякс запрос.

Comment: переменная- флаг  не подходит поскольку запрос выполняется при загрузке страницы. переменная будет полем window, как глобального объекта страницы.  при каждом запуске страницы window пересоздается

Comment: на самом деле, вопрос изложен, вероятно, не точно. При нажатии на указанную ссылку происходит нормальный переход на страницу или срабатывает ajax-загрузка контента?

Comment: происходит нормальный переход на страницу

Comment: ест несколько страниц, каждая из которых имеет  одинаковую базовую структуру, а именно в левой части на каждой из них находится список страниц.

Comment: можно сказать два div-а в первом - ссылки, а во втором содержимое страницы

Comment: после первого нажатия происходит полная перерисовка страницы.  потом вызывается  загрузка данных в $(document).ready(). поскольку страница уже сформирована (блок div со ссылками ) то можно нажать на ссылку.

Comment: @evgeniy.se т.е. сценарий такой: нажали-обновилась-сразу снова нажали-обновилась-сразу снова нажали... ?

Comment: да,  именно так.

Comment: была такая же проблема, если сервер справляется, то стоит делать запрос к разным страницам, а не к одной и той же. Синхронный сервер от одной не ответит, от разных может потянуть. /?p=1, /?p=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как выяснились все детали ситуации, оказалось, что стандартные методы здесь не подходят.

Кроме ответов "возьмите сервер получше" или "оптимизируйте код, почему он валится от двух запросов", можно придумать только такой костыль: при нажатии на ссылку выставлять "флаг" в localStorage, независимый от текущей страницы.

```
$("#btnAdministra").on('click', function(e){
    var delay = 10; //для подстраховки: сколько секунд выждать перед повторным запросом
    var contentLoading = localStorage.getItem('contentLoading');
    if(contentLoading && (new Date()) - contentLoading < delay * 1000){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('contentLoading', +(new Date()));
});
```

С приведенным выше кодом ссылка будет работать только по прошествии 10 секунд после очередного нажатия. Понятное дело, так не пойдет. Поэтому, в колбеке AJAX-запроса подгрузки страницы нужно добавить код, который удалит флаг:

```
localStorage.removeItem('contentLoading')
```

Comment: может результат аякса вставляется в страницу append'ами, много таких аппендов валят страницу, или проблема в верстке, после нескольких аппендов каша.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Я так понял, что ссылка работает как обычная ссылка - нажали, произошел переход на Administrators.html, а там уже при загрузке вызвался ajax. В таком случае, не идет речи о множественных append'ах.

Comment: как можно много раз нажать на такую ссылку, после нажатия если происходит переход?

Comment: @Jean-Claude честно говоря, даже не задумался. Вы правы, нельзя. Каюсь, тупанул. Тогда нужно немного подправить ответ.

Comment: убрал все append-ы  проблема осталась. суть в том что запрос асинхронный. сервер еще не выдал ответ на первый запрос, когда к нему поступает следующий. Доступа к серверу нету.

Comment: он не подходит поскольку каждый раз будет происходить загрузка страницы и заново привязываться обработчики событий.

Comment: @evgeniy.se попробуйте новый вариант. обновил ответ.

Comment: все супер. спасибо.

Comment: @evgeniy.se если ответ вам подошел - пометьте его верным, пожалуйста. Галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: p.s. а как таким образом можно обработать обновление страницы посредством F5 ?

Comment: @evgeniy.se сложный вопрос. в контексте текущего обсуждения он уже "не в тему", т.к. ставит совсем другие вопросы. И кроме меня здесь ваш вопрос особо никто не увидит, а у меня, в данный момент, к сожалению, нет времени ответить исчерпывающе. Создайте новый вопрос, не уточняя про ссылку и все лишнее. Просто: открывается страница, на загрузке срабатывает ajax, что делать, чтобы избежать многократного ajax при обновлении страницы.

Comment: @evgeniy.se я бы сконцентрировал внимание на том, почему у вас падает что-то там при нескольких ajax-запроса. Что конкретно падает? какая ошибка? Вероятно, нужно не городить костыли, мешающие клиенту нормально взаимодействовать с сайтом, а исправить причину падений на сервере. Возможно, просто нужно настроить должным образом сервер.